# App authorization failed in XERO: unauthorized_client : Unknown client or client not enabled

Tags: xero-api

I'd like to create my custom Xero app, but unfortunately, user can not authorize in it. I use this [guide](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow)

When user opens authorization link like that:

```
https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=EC5X0XXXXXXC43BXXXXXXX08CC77741&redirect_uri=https://service.com/finish&scope=openid profile email accounting.transactions&state=123
```

an error appears

"unauthorized_client : Unknown client or client not enabled"

How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue while trying to integrate my app using the Xero OAuth2 code flow (connecting from a web app) and what solved it for me was generating a Client Secret in the Xero app configuration screen. This seemed to "enable" my app, event though the Client Secret won't be used by my app in the OAuth2 flow.